# Typescript in IntelliJ not generating js files when tsconfig declaration is turned on

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, declaration, tsconfig

I have the following in my tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "static/gen/",
        "include": ["test/**/*"],
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": false
    },
}
```

Whenever "declaration" is turned on the .js files stop being generated from the .ts files. Everything works fine until I turn on "declaraction" (with "emitDeclarationOnly" as false).

I am correct in thinking that .js files ARE supposed to be generated when declaration is turned on (with emitDeclarationOnly=false), correct? Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77406133/edit) the question to include a [mre] (all of the files and content, software versions, etc.) and clarify with detailed reproduction steps how you are actually attempting to compile your code (e.g. via [`tsc`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), by using the [compiler context action in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html), etc.). See [ask].

Comment: `js` files are correctly emitted for me when using your config, using both the **Compile** action on the **Typescript** widget and **Recompile on changes** option. Are you sure that the file(s) you have issues with are included in your `tsconfig.json`? Also, what IDE and Typescript versions do you work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the include directive inside the compilerOptions directive, but it needed to be in the root of the config.